# An array of pointers to two dimensional arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I have 10 two-dimensional arrays of chars and I need to make an array of pointers pointing to those two dimensional arrays and then I need to print those two dimensional arrays. 
So far I've done this:(I have already declared the arrays)

```
char(*s1)[9][15] = &p1;
char(*s2)[9][15] = &p2;
char(*s3)[9][15] = &p3;
char(*s4)[9][15] = &p4;
char(*s5)[9][15] = &p5;
char(*s6)[9][15] = &p6;
char(*s7)[9][15] = &p7;
char(*s8)[9][15] = &p8;
char(*s9)[9][15] = &p9;
char(*s10)[9][15] = &p10;

char *pointers[10] = {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10};

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
      cout << [0][i][j]; // this is just for the first two-dimensional array
   }
}
```

So this doesn't print out the array as it should. What can I do? Please help.

Comment: Putting aside the question itself, I think you are working in a wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

1. Correct `pointers`'s type.
2. Get the pointer to array, dereference to get the array, and access the array.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
#define array(x) char x[9][15] = {};for(int i=0;i<9;i++)for(int j=0;j<9;j++)x[i][j]='!'+i+j;

int main(void) {
    array(p1)
    array(p2)
    array(p3)
    array(p4)
    array(p5)
    array(p6)
    array(p7)
    array(p8)
    array(p9)
    array(p10)

    char(*s1)[9][15] = &p1;
    char(*s2)[9][15] = &p2;
    char(*s3)[9][15] = &p3;
    char(*s4)[9][15] = &p4;
    char(*s5)[9][15] = &p5;
    char(*s6)[9][15] = &p6;
    char(*s7)[9][15] = &p7;
    char(*s8)[9][15] = &p8;
    char(*s9)[9][15] = &p9;
    char(*s10)[9][15] = &p10;

    char (*pointers[10])[9][15] = {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10};

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
          cout << (*pointers[0])[i][j]; // this is just for the first two-dimensional array
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works now. This really helped me.